# multiple toggle doesn't work correctly

Tags: jquery

I've implemented a toggle event, but it doesn't work correctly.

If I click one of these images every class toggle and I just would like to toggle the active class.

```
<script>
            $("#img-01").click(function () {
                $(".crp-list").toggle();
            });
            $("#img-02").click(function () {
                $(".crp-list").toggle();
            });
            $("#img-03").click(function () {
                $(".crp-list").toggle();
            });
</script>
```

Here is my html code..

```
 <div class="toggle-content">
      <img src="Images/icon.png" alt="" id="img-01" />
          <ul class="crp-list" style="display: none">
             <li class="content-one comments hidden">
                  Content 1
             </li>

         </ul>
  </div>

 <div class="toggle-content">
      <img src="Images/icon.png" alt="" id="img-02" />
          <ul class="crp-list" style="display: none">
             <li class="content-one comments hidden">
                  Content 3
             </li>

         </ul>
  </div>

 <div class="toggle-content">
      <img src="Images/icon.png" alt="" id="img-03" />
          <ul class="crp-list" style="display: none">
             <li class="content-one comments hidden">
                  Content 3
             </li>

         </ul>
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: $(this).next().toggle(); Try this. or go for $(this).parent().find('.crp-list').toggle();

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[attrribute starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)** selector to shorten your code as well as using `$(this)` and **[.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next)** to target only the next immediate sibling of clicked image which is `.crp-list` list:

```
$('[id^="img-"]').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

Comment: Many thanks for all of you..it works fine now. I am facing now another problem the toggle doesn't move down probably..I tried this code..

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
$(this).next(".crp-list").toggle();
```

instead of

```
$(".crp-list").toggle();
```

Further your code can be optimized to

```
$("#img-01, #img-02, #img-03").click(function () {
    $(this).next(".crp-list").toggle();
});
```

However, I would recommend to give a common class to image and then use class selector to bind event. like

*HTML*

```
<img class="image" src="Images/icon.png" alt="" id="img-01" />
<img class="image" src="Images/icon.png" alt="" id="img-02" />
<img class="image" src="Images/icon.png" alt="" id="img-03" />
```

*JS*

```
$(".image").click(function () {
    $(this).next(".crp-list").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#img-01, #img-02, #img-03").click(function () {
    $(this).next(".crp-list").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".toggle-content img").click(function () { 
   $(this).next('ul').toggle();
});
```

Now you can do this by single line code